# How to get attractive table of contents in Latex

Tags: titlesec

I am currently using the `\tableofcontents` from `\usepackage{titlesec}` to insert the table of contents in my report. Are there any templates available in LaTeX for a more attractive table of contents format?

I wanted something that is similar to the pic attached below:

[image]

Comment: I would recommend you use the `booktabs` package -- see the associated documentation on how to do tables.  Also, it would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that shows an example of that table that you think needs improving.

Comment: I would suggest the tocloft package to fine tune the table of contents, list of figures, list of tables (as the name implies).

Comment: fncychap package is having few styles. Are there other packages similar to this? I got it from the following link: https://texblog.org/2012/07/03/fancy-latex-chapter-styles/

Comment: What is it about the default table of contents that you want to change?  "similar to this picture" is a vague request.

Comment: What i wanted is a package similar to fncychap which provides choice of different templates for table of contents and chapter titles to be implemented within the report class.